# I want to display images in a more controlled manner

Tags: javascript

i had tried much of this but nothing on the internet works. I want to display two image frames like thing where only image should be displayed. now i have 7 to 8 images and when 1 out of two images are clicked at starting then the variable assigned two that image increases by 1 and two new images are placed on those frame repeating the same procedure. The input from the user should be just clicking on 1 of those picture. help please.

Comment: What have you already tried ?

We can help you in fixing errors, but providing end-to-end solution on stackoverflow is a wrong expectation.

Comment: And when you reach the end, what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving to much details, so improvising. Cycle images by two.

HTML:

```
<div class="image image-left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1" alt="">
</div>
<div class="image image-right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2" alt="">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var images = [
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/5',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/6',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7',
        'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/8'
    ],
    index = 0,
    imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.image img');


[].slice.call(imgs).forEach(function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
        index = (index + 2) % images.length;
        imgs[0].src = images[index];
        imgs[1].src = images[index + 1];
    };
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D8Ufu/

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your description (because you have not supplied much info) is a scenerio where,

you have image resources in an array (simply name of images if they are in same folder, their relative path otherwise)

```
images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", ...]
```

and two frames containing two **img** tag may be like,

```
<img id="frame1" class="gallery"....
<img id="frame2" class="gallery"...
```

.

Now what we can do is on clicking any of image we should get first two images from the array, replace the **src** of **img** tags and push the current ones in the same array. You may write it like,

```
$('.gallery').on('click', function() {

  var img1 = $('#frame1'),
      img2 = $('#frame2'),
      im1  = img1.attr('src'),
      im2  = img2.attr('src');

  img1.attr('src', images.shift())
  images.push(im1)
  img2.attr('src', images.shift())
  images.push(im2)

})
```

though this is not the best and smart way to do it, but it is quite simple and will do your work.